# how to get the color code from Gradient in android ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created the ring shaped curved gradient for the progress bar, to make it curved from the edge i have created the ring shaped dot item in layer-list and set one at the starting of the progress and the other one at the bottom. The issue here is gradient color effect is dynamic so i have to change the bottom dot color to same as gradient bottom color, is there a way to get the gradient bottom color code dynamically ? Attached image is the exact layout i'm trying to implement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/gradientDrawable">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.67"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:thicknessRatio="40.0">
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#E85E44"
                    android:endColor="#FF9C00"
                    android:startColor="#FF9C00"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/topDot" android:bottom="@dimen/_126sdp">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="5000"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <solid android:color="#FF9C00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/bottomDot">
        <rotate>
            <inset android:insetBottom="@dimen/_126sdp">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="5000"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="@dimen/_3sdp"
                    android:useLevel="false">

                    <solid android:color="#E85E44" />
                </shape>
            </inset>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Here is the image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJMDp.png